# Arcpy: formatting string for file name

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder

I have the following question about formatting a string which I use to create output file names.

I loop a SearchCursor to create .png file. I extract two columns form the cursor e.g. "GMS_ID" and "ID". (codepart - with `arcpy.da.SearchCursor("dbk_object_test_SpatialJoin2",['GMS_ID','ID','SHAPE@']) as cur:`)

Then I concatenate the two columns like:

```
vakkrt_name = str(row[0]) + "_" + str(row[1])
```

Almost at the end I use:

```
outpng = r"D:\\arcpy\\output\\DBK_" + format(vakkrt_name) + ".png"
```

to create the file reference and after that I use:

```
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, outpng,df,
                          df_export_width=1600,
                          df_export_height=1200,
                          resolution=200)
```

to really create the file on disk.

The result is something like:

**DBK_1234.0_5678.0.png**

Can you help me by disabling the decimal point probably by using the Format method.

Answer (score 8):

The format of your 2 fields is probably double. Turn them to integer first (with or without the string.format() method, but the latter is more elegant):

```
vakkrt_name = str(int(row[0])) + "_" + str(int(row[1]))
```

or

```
vakkrt_name = "{}_{}".format(int(row[0]), int(row[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you, GISGe. This method works fine for me. Problem solved!